# Serving static media in django application

Tags: django

I notice that when I reference my java scripts and static image files from my templates, they show up in development, but not from the production server.  From development, I access them as such:

```
<img src="/my_proj/media/css/images/collapsed.png" />
```

but from production, I have to remove the project directory:

```
<img src="/media/css/images/collapsed.png" />
```

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with regard to serving static media.

I'm caught between a number of seemingly different options for serving static media in Django.  On one hand, it's been recommended that I use [django-staticfiles](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-staticfiles) to serve media.  On the other I see reference to [STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) in the documentation (with caveats about use in production).

I have small .png files of "plus" and "minus" symbols for use in some of my jQuery scripts.  In addition, the scripts themselves need to be referenced.

1) Am I correctly categorizing scripts and site images as static media?
2) What is the best method to access this media (from production)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't keep the URLs hardcoded that way.

If you're running thedev version of Django, you should [check this doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

If you're not, for simplicity, you can use {{ MEDIA_URL }} and configure that variable in your settings for dev and for production.

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/media/css..." />
```

Keep in mind that you'll have to use RequestContext, [see more here on docs here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) and [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS).

Also, you should server all your static files directly trough a proper webserver. You can configure apache or nginx to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Sigh. There is only one way to serve static media in production, and that is to get the webserver - eg Apache - to do it. Django-staticfiles is for development only, and this is clearly stated throughout the documentation.